# Python- TypeError being thrown on a tuple. For MIT Open Courseware Introduction to 6.00 Prob Set 2

Tags: python, tuples, typeerror

I'm a little lost on why this typeError is being thrown.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    evaluate_poly(polyTestTwo,-13)
  File "C:\Users\robert\Desktop\programming\MIT open courseware\ps2\ps2_newton.py", line  
22, in evaluate_poly
    valHolder+=((poly[i]*x)**i)
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers
```

Here is my code:

```
def evaluate_poly(poly, x):
    """
    Computes the polynomial function for a given value x. Returns that value.

    Example:
    >>> poly = (0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 9.3, 7.0)    # f(x) = 7x^4 + 9.3x^3 + 5x^2
    >>> x = -13
    >>> print evaluate_poly(poly, x)  # f(-13) = 7(-13)^4 + 9.3(-13)^3 + 5(-13)^2
    180339.9

    poly: tuple of numbers, length > 0
    x: number
    returns: float
    """
    valHolder=0.0
    for i in poly:
        valHolder+=((poly[i]*x)**i)
        i=i+1
        if i==(len(poly))-1:
            return float(valHolder)
            break
```

The input I put to get this particular error is as follows.

```
>>>polyTest=(0.0,0.0,5.0,9.3,7.0) 
>>>evaluate_poly(polyTest,-13)
```

Any idea what's causing it? I thought tuples could have floats as values?

Comment: Note that the formula example output makes no sense if you interpret it as `(7 * -13) ** 4`, etc; that sum comes to 66812013.671, not 180339.9. I don't know *how* to interpret that sum, as `(7 * -13 ** 4)`, etc. sums to -221204.1 instead.

Answer (score 4):

Your loop `for i in poly` iterates over the *values* of `poly`, not the indices.

If you need indices, use the `enumerate()` function to add these; you get both the index *and* the value in your loop:

```
def evaluate_poly(poly, x):
    valHolder = 0.0
    for i, value in enumerate(poly):
        valHolder += (value * x) ** i
    return valHolder
```

You do not need to test for the end of the loop here either, nor turn the result into a float; it is already a float.